# Date format for sitemap

Tags: javascript, meteor, sitemap

I'm using [gadicohen:sitemaps](https://atmospherejs.com/gadicohen/sitemaps) with Meteor to create my sitemaps and I'm not sure how to set the lastmod date field. The documents state not to use new Date(), so what date format should I use.

`{ page: '/x', lastmod: new Date() },`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They aren't saying not to use `Date` as a type, they are saying that you should not create a `new Date()` every time the sitemap is requested.

Instead, keep in your collection the time that the page was last modified, and use that in the sitemap